# SQL query execute with using schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-schema

I have two database `my_cf_1` and `my_cf_2`.

I move two databases (`my_cf_1`, `my_cf_2`) to single database `my_cf` using schema.

`my_cf` database has two schema `my_cf_1` and `my_cf_2`.

Query example:

Old case (I have two databases)

```
USE my_cf_1

SELECT * 
FROM ORDERS O 
JOIN my_cf_2.DBO.COMPANY C ON O.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID
```

New case (I have a single database with two schemas)

```
USE my_cf

SELECT * 
FROM my_cf_1.ORDERS O 
JOIN my_cf_2.COMPANY C ON O.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID
```

My issue: I have a lot of queries. I must change all queries. So how can I execute query `Use Database.SchemaName` scope?

Is this possible?

```
USE my_cf.my_cf_1

SELECT * 
FROM ORDERS O 
JOIN my_cf_2.COMPANY C ON O.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible. Other than refactoring your entire codebase, you could drop all the tables in `my_cf2` but it. online. You can then create synonyms pointing to the new tables. This will allow you to gradually refactor your codebase

```
USE my_cf_2
CREATE SYNONYM DBO.COMPANY FOR my_cf.my_cf2.COMPANY
```

With this synonym this query:

```
SELECT * from my_cf2.DBO.COMPANY
```

will be identical to:

```
SELECT * from my_cf.my_cf2.COMPAN
```